# mongoose geolocation + distance query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am unsure how I recreate the following `.find` query into a mongoose query:

```js
db.places.find({
  loc: { $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [[-74, 40.74], 100 / 3963.2] } }
});
```

I have set up the scheme

```js
const AdScheme = new Schema({
  location: {
    coordinates: [{ 0: Number, 1: Number }]
  },
  type: String,
  name: String
});

export default mongoose.model("campaign", AdScheme);
```

but now I need to do a find query and this is not a simple `.findOne()`.

Could anyone please give me an example of turning the above into a mongoosedb query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mongoose [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/geojson.html) it says mongoose has a helper method for [$geoWithin](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-within).

First, schema must be updated like this:

```js
const AdScheme = new Schema({
  location: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: 'Point',
      enum: ['Point']
    },
    coordinates: [Number]
  },
  type: String,
  name: String
});
```

And then query like this:

```js
AdModel.find().where('loc')
  .within({ center: [50,50], radius: 10, unique: true, spherical: true })
```

Another option would be using mongoDB [$geoNear](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) aggregation.

Then you can use it within mongoose like this:

```
const geoNearOptions: {
  ... //todo
}

AdModel.aggregate([
  { $geoNear: geoNearOptions}
])
```